# Nginx 403 permission denied, chown/chmod don't seem to work

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, permission-denied, nginx-location, nginx-config

I can't get my nginx working, I am getting permission denied.

Tried:

```
sudo chmod o+x /home
sudo chmod o+x /home/path-to-www
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/path-to-www/www
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/path-to-www/www/
service nginx restart
```

**The above did not work.**

So I tried:

```
sudo chown -R path-to-www:path-to-www /home/path-to-www/www
```

plus:

setting the nginx user to path-to-www and retarting again.

**This didn't work as well.**

I am out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: hi, paste some logs please; besides, the last chown seems odd, I mean do you really use *path-to-www* as user as owner?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. To answer your question, no, I am using just here path-to-www just for an example in order not to disclose my username. Meanwhile I just solved it - it was the Selinux which I disabled and after reboot it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: It was Selinux. I disabled it and rebooted and it worked.